# Let $A$ be a $m×n$ matrix, prove or disprove if $AA^t$ is invertible then $m\leq n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I got this claim on my test today:
Let $A$ be a matix of order $m×n$ prove or disprove, if $AA^t$ is invertible then $m\leq n$.
I'm pretty sure this claim is false,
can anyone confirm and if I am wrong what is the proof to this claim?

Answer (score 2):

Because $(A.A^t)_{m \times m}$ is invertible, so r$(A.A^t)=m$.

But r$(A.A^t)\leq $ min {r$(A$),r$(A^t)$} $\leq$ min{$m,n$}.
Now suppose that $m>n$, then $m =$ r$(A.A^t) \leq$  min{$m,n$} =$n$, a contradiction.
Thus $m \leq n$.

Answer (score 1):

This is true. Note that if $AA^t$ is an invertible, then $\mbox{rank}(AA^t)=m$.

Observe that $\dim \mbox{im}(A^t)\geq \dim \mbox{im}(AA^t)$.  Thus $\mbox{rank}(A^t) \geq\mbox{rank}(AA^t)$. But $\mbox{rank}(A^t) = \mbox{rank}(A)$, so  $m=\mbox{rank}(AA^t) \leq   \mbox{rank}(A^t)= \mbox{rank}(A) \leq n $